# How do I get the data from a html script tag into my python function?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get the data that I have stored inside of a script tag in my html file to my python file so that I can use it in a python function, does anyone have any idea how I could achieve this? Here's my html code:

```
<textarea id="rendezook" class="rendezook"></textarea>
<button onclick="get_text();">Valider</button>
<script>
    function get_text() {
        var x = document.getElementById("rendezook")
        location.href = "/validate_comment?rendezook=" + encodeURIComponent(x.value);
        console.log(x.value)
    }
</script>
```

And then this is my python file:

```
@app.route('/validate_comment')
def validate_comment(item_id=None):
    print("test")
    print(request.args.get("rendezook"))
    print("test2")
    return redirect(url_for('msr_edit', item_id=72))
```

test and test2 are not getting printed so it is not entering the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use a form that's submitted via a GET request:

```
<form action="/validate_comment">
  <textarea name="rendezook" class="rendezook"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Valider</button>
</form>
```

This will result in an URL like `/validate_comment?rendezook=some_value_here`, so you can access it [via `request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#the-request-object) (as it looks like you're using Flask):

```
@app.route('/validate_comment')
def validate_comment():
    print("yeet", request.args.get("rendezook"))
    return redirect(url_for('msr_edit', item_id=72))
```

---

Based on comments, if you're unable to use a form for some reason, then:

```
<textarea id="rendezook" class="rendezook"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Valider</button>
<script>
function test() {
    var x = document.getElementById("rendezook");
    location.href = "/validate_comment?rendezook=" + encodeURIComponent(x.value);
}
</script>
```

---

## EDIT 2

Here's a minimal example that provably works :)

```
from flask import request, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/validate_comment")
def validate_comment(item_id=None):
    x = request.args.get("rendezook")
    return f"you said {x}"


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return """
<textarea id="rendezook" class="rendezook"></textarea>
<button onclick="get_text();">Valider</button>
<script>
    function get_text() {
        var x = document.getElementById("rendezook")
        location.href = "/validate_comment?rendezook=" + encodeURIComponent(x.value);
        console.log(x.value)
    }
</script>
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: the problem with this is that i am already inside of a form tag so I can't make a new one, do you think there is a way to do this but without the form tags?

Comment: Well, in that case just `location.href = '/validate_comment?rendezook=' + encodeURIComponent(x.value)` ...

Comment: I have changed the href in the <a> tag with this ```<a location.href = '/validate_comment?rendezook=' + encodeURIComponent(x.value)>Valider</a>``` but it does not seem to call my python function anymore, did i do something wrong? (sorry if I did I am fairly new to html)

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see that! I have added the location.href exactly like you sent it but it still isn't going into my python function, is it maybe because the python function expects the href to be just "/validate_comment"?

Comment: I have edited my question with the way my code looks like now

Comment: I did and I don't get why my code isn't working if this is... I'm confused

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the opening `<textarea>` tag, for one – make sure your markup is valid?

Comment: the href inside of the script in my html file doesn't seem to be working, I just tried putting just ```href = "/validate_comment"``` inside of my script tags and this worked before but now it did not

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I didn't see that but the problem is still persisting

Comment: I really don't know what else to say without additional context. If my EDIT 2 example works out of the box, then the issue is somewhere in your code that I can't see.

Comment: well the only difference I can see is that I have my html code in a different file than my python code yet I don't know why that would even be an issue